# Word embedding for Non-NLP words

Tags: word-embeddings, bert

I would like to embed words with a context, but that is not "Natural Language" - but just a list of words about more or less the same topic. Is there a way to use this context for the embedding ? I suppose Bert and other pre-trained models won't work out of the box, as they are trained for Natural Language ?

Comment: Reading about a list of words about more or less the same topic makes me think of topic modeling or keyphrase extraction. Have you tried BERTopic and the sorts?

Comment: It's not very clear what you mean by 'non-NLP words'. Can you please give an example? Also you're talking about training your own embeddings, right? How much data do you have?